# JPA xml mapping not finding fields

Tags: java, jpa, orm, eclipselink

I have the following class:

```java
package lt.vic.valdos.domain.valda;

public class Valda implements java.io.Serializable {
    private long id;
    private Long valdosKodas;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Long getValdosKodas() {
        return valdosKodas;
    }
}
```

and the following orm.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entity-mappings
        xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/eclipselink_orm_2_1.xsd"
        version="2.1">
    <entity class="lt.vic.valdos.domain.valda.Valda">
        <table name="VALDOS" schema="VLD" />
        <attributes>
            <id name="id" />
            <basic name="id">
                <column name="vld_id" />
                <return-insert return-only="true" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="valdosKodas">
                <column name="valdos_kodas" />
            </basic>
        </attributes>
    </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

When I deploy this in glassfish, i get the following error:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-7215] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Could not load the field named [id] on the class [class lt.vic.valdos.domain.valda.Valda]. Ensure there is a corresponding field with that name defined on the class.
```

The class is in a jar that is included into a web application as a maven dependency. The orm.xml is in /WEB-INF/classes/META-INF of the web application.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this one out myself. For some reason EclipseLink requires a setter on a class. Once I add private setters everything seems fine. Why the setters are needed (mapping accessors should default to FIELD) remains a mystery but it is not that important for me. Adding  access="FIELD" to all entity attributes also fixes the problem without the setters.

Answer (score 1):

You should be specifying the id as generated using the IDENTITY strategy:

```
<id name="id">
    <column name="vld_id"/>
    <generated-value strategy="IDENTITY"/>
</id>
```

This strategy will automatically read the database provided id back into the new object upon successful commit.  The EclipseLink returning statement functionality is only applicable to basic mappings because id is already covered by Identity ID generation.

Comment: This strategy works only if the database generates primary keys based on identity table. However in my case the underlying database is Oracle, which generates primary keys on sequences. There are on-insert triggers set up by DBA which do the sequence.nextval for you. I am aware that there is a sequence based strategy as well but i do not have select permissions on the sequences (idiotic DBA policy) which leaves return-insert as the only option.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add the column description for the id column to your *id* element, instead of using an extra *basic* element. As in `<id name="id"> <column name="vld_id" /> ... </id>`, without an extra `<basic name="id"> ...`.

From my own experience (some time ago now), it's probably easier to use annotations to define your mappings.

Comment: I've tried adding a <column> tag inside <id>. However, i cannot remove the <basic> since i need the eclipselink's <return-insert> tag (old DB design with primary key triggers) which cannot be placed inside <id>. I am still getting the same result with both <id> and <basic>. I am aware that annotation approach is easier and everything works if I use annotations. But I don't like the dependency on JPA in my domain jar.

Comment: If you removed the basic only for testing, does the exception go away?

Comment: The exception stays even if i remove the <basic> for the id field.

Comment: If it's working using annotations, I'd go with it. You could probably use an extra class layer to shield your domain objects from the JPA specifics (like a [Row Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/rowDataGateway.html) or some such). Of course, maintaining that extra layer can get tedious if you have a large code base, or your domain objects change frequently.